# Trouble making dynamics links

Tags: views, routes, blocks

I have two dynamic links that I want to put in a block, e.g. http://example.com/series/bomberman-jetters/node/add/gallery/82 ("series" is the content type, and "bomberman jetters" is the node title), http://example.com/series/bomberman-jetters/node/add/reivew/82 ("82" is the node ID).

I want to change the URL depending on what node is being viewed. Like if it's viewing node 99 then the links in the block should be changed to http://example.com/series/bomberman-jetters/node/add/gallery/99.

So what I did is insert `<?php
print "<a href='#overlay=node/add/review/" . arg(1) . "'>Add album</a>";
?>` but it doesn't work in Drupal 7. The link is correct but it doesn't lead you to creating the node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link code worked for me when I tried it on a random page so it's hard to tell what could be wrong from the information you provided. Generally a better way for creating links in code would be the [l function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7):

```
<?php print l(t('Add album'), 'node/add/review/' . arg(1)); ?>
```

Drupal will handle the use of admin overlay automatically if it's enabled. Another thing I noticed is that adding `arg(1)` for `nid` at the end of node creation pages serves no purpose generally. If it's used by a module or custom code for something then it's a different story though.